# lateinit property newTrack has not been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

When I start my app it crash and I get get Following error message in logcat:

"lateinit property newTrack has not been initialized"

I have locate the problem to my "showdata" function, but I can't see what the problem is.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    val collection = "song"
    val artistName = "name"
    val trackName = "track"
    var docId =""

    lateinit var newTrack : SoundTrack
    lateinit var  db : FirebaseFirestore
    lateinit var alSongs : ArrayList<HashMap<String,Any>>
    lateinit var adapter: SimpleAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        alSongs = ArrayList()
        addData.setOnClickListener(this)
        updateInfo.setOnClickListener(this)
        deleteInfo.setOnClickListener(this)
        IsData.setOnItemClickListener(itemClick)

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection(collection).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, e ->
            if(e != null) Log.d("fireStore", e.message)
            showData()

        }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            //add new data by input
            R.id.addData ->{

                val hm = HashMap<String, Any>()
                hm.set(newTrack.name,ArtistName.text.toString())
                hm.set(newTrack.track,track.text.toString())
                db.collection(collection).document(ArtistName.text.toString()).set(hm).
                    addOnSuccessListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Data unSuccessfully added : ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            }
            //Update input
            R.id.updateInfo -> {

                val hm = HashMap<String, Any>()
                hm.set(newTrack.name,ArtistName.text.toString())
                hm.set(newTrack.track,track.text.toString())
                db.collection(collection).document(docId).update(hm)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show() }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Data unSuccessfully updated : ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
            }
            //delete Input 
            R.id.deleteInfo -> {
                db.collection(collection).whereEqualTo(newTrack.name,docId).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                        results ->
                    for(doc in results){
                        db.collection(collection).document(doc.id).delete()
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Data unSuccessfully updated : ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cant get data reference: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val itemClick = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val hm = alSongs.get(position)
        docId = hm.get(newTrack.name).toString()
        ArtistName.setText(hm.get(newTrack.name).toString())
        track.setText(hm.get(newTrack.name).toString())
    }
//Show input data

    fun showData(){
        db.collection(collection).get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            alSongs.clear()
            for(doc in result){
                val hm = HashMap<String,Any>()
                hm.set(newTrack.name,doc.get(newTrack.name).toString())
                hm.set(newTrack.track,doc.get(newTrack.track).toString())
                alSongs.add(hm)
            }
            adapter = SimpleAdapter(this,alSongs,R.layout.row_data,
                arrayOf(newTrack.name,newTrack.track),
                intArrayOf(R.id.txName, R.id.TxTrack))
            IsData.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your stacktrace?

Comment: You never set `newTrack`. And then you try to build `SimpleAdapter` with `newTrack.name` and so on. `lateinit var` means "I promise to put a value here" and you didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `lateinit` is to prevent nullability. When you use `lateinit` you are saying that by the time I want to use this value it will be initialized. When you try to use it before you initialize it you get this error so you need to initialize it first

You can use `if(::newTrack.isInitialized)` like others have said but IMO that defeats the purpose of lateinit

Comment: Now the app does't crash and press all my buttons, but I can't insert a new value to my array. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize newTrack variable or check is it initialized

```
if(::newTrack.isInitialized){
  // logic
}else{
 newTrack = SoundTrack()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can using `.isInitialized` property one can check initialization state of a lateinit variable.

```
if(this::newTrack.isInitialized){
    //newTrack is initialized
}else{
    //newTrack is not initialized
}
```